# Getting the data from database using Date datatype column.

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

iam developing one application.In that saved the database with datatypes integer,test and date.So now i trying to get the data from database using below query.

```
  NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Sno,name FROM school where Date='%@'",date];.
```

date contain the data with NSDate format.When i run this one i didn't get the single row of data.So how to retrieve the data using that date value.(Date column data format is MM-dd-yy(01-22-12)).

Answer (score 0):

You need a NSDateFormatter.

Then set the date formatter to the format your database date is.  [This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) should help you find such format.

Then, for your query, use your date formatter stringFromDate method like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM-mm-yy"];
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Sno,name FROM school where Date='%@'",[df stringFromDate:date]];
```

Comment: How are dates being stored in your database? What format (yyyy-mm-dd)? Also, is date an NSDate?

Comment: IN database,dates are stored in MM-dd-yy format.And that column datatype is Date.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

1.**Creation Table**

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];

[db open];

[db executeUpdate:@"create table if not exists UserTbl(eventname text,eventdate date)"];

FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM UserTbl"];

while([results next])
{
     ReminderObject *Reminder = [[ReminderObject alloc] init];
     Reminder.EventTitleString = [results stringForColumn:@"eventname"];
     Reminder.EventDateString = [results stringForColumn:@"eventdate"];
     [ReminderListArray addObject:Reminder];
}
[db close];
```

2.**Insertion**

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];

[db open];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
dateFormat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
dateFormat.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

NSLog(@".........DateString...%@",dateString);
//NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO user (edited) VALUES (\"%@\")", dateString];
BOOL success =  [db executeUpdate:@"insert into UserTbl(eventname,eventdate) values(?,?);",
                 Reminder.EventTitleString,dateString, nil];
[db close];
```